# Как перенести файлы bootmgr и BOOTNXT?

Tags: windows, boot, активация

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Недавно купил ssd и установил Windows 10, не отформатировав старый HDD.
Windows 10 сама активировалась (цифровая лицензия).
Я не спец в этой области, но думаю, что bootmgr и BOOTNXT нельзя удалять, могу ли я перенести их на установленный ssd и как-то задать путь загрузки?
Подскажите, как грамотно поступить в данном случае?

Comment: Методом тыка пробовал? Вообще, если 10 активировалась, то она слепок железа отправила в майкрософт и при следующей установке активируется сама.

Comment: Нет, не пробовал.Что это значит?

Comment: Метод тыка? Ну тыкаешь на угад и смотришь что получится. При наличии бэкапов - один из самых эффективных способов.

Comment: Я ssd поставил на место hdd, а hdd  вместо DVD привода. Я в ssd все настроил. Вот теперь хочу  отфарматировать hdd. Но, в управление дисками заметил что разделы восстановления в hdd, а в ssd нет. А вот эти bootmgr и BOOTNXT файлы есть в hdd а в ssd нет.

Comment: Просто тупо скопировать эти файлы думаю не прокатит, вот спрашиваю. Нужно как-то изменив путь этих файлов скопировать в ssd, но увы не нашел как(

Comment: Отключи винт и посмотри что будет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Только вот все равно ssd зависим от hdd

Если не успели уже инсталлировать массу программ в систему, я бы рекомендовал переустановить Windows 10 на чистый SSD, предварительно убрав из системы старый HDD. Иначе есть шанс (особенно, если вы заходите в систему через учетную запись MS) слёта активации (возможно, с потерей баллов), придётся заново проходить эту процедуру.

Поскольку система уже активирована, она передала :D данные в MS, и, если прошло 3 дня, можете смело переинсталлировать её. Да, вы потеряете (точнее, приобретёте, но это вопрос семантики) [баллы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/790372/), но, возможно, успеете минимизировать их потери.

Comment: Увы, но уже успел(. Похожу месяца 2-3 с ним, потом норм переустановлю. Спасибо за совет

Comment: Позвольте полюбопытствовать, о каких баллах идёт речь? Ввели баллы? Windows 10 стоит только на паре компьютеров, потому не особо в курсе

Comment: @AlexeyKozlov Создал вопрос-ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/790372/

Answer (score 0):

В итоге, сделал резерв 2 файлов, переместил их на ssd и отформатировал D. Вроде норм. Только вот все равно ssd зависим от hdd.

Comment: Сделай как порекомендовал @ViktorTomilov. Отруби лишние накопители и переустанови ТОЛЬКО на ssd.