# Что такое баллы активации Windows 10? Сколько их всего и зачем они нужны?

Tags: windows, администрирование, windows-10, активация

На компьютере стоит Windows 10, собираюсь сменить жёсткий диск (видеокарту, сетевую карту, процессор, память и т.п.), не слетит ли активация? Читал о каких-то баллах, которые тратятся при смене железа, как это происходит и можно ли это контролировать?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Это характерно не только для Windows 10, просто в Windows 10, в отличие от предыдущих выпусков, онлайн-активация стала применяться по умолчанию (+убрали SLIC-активацию, как класс, хотя возможность оффлайн-активации для вендоров оставили, но она стала сложнее на порядок).

Система онлайн-активации Volume Activation 2.0 (VA2) была предложена Microsoft ещё для Windows Vista в 2006 году и внедрена для активации не только Windows, но и Office, Visio и серверов. Особенностью подобного подхода является то, что ключ продукта, в общем-то, пользователю не нужен (более того, первый месяц использования продукта он может вообще не задумываться об активации, своеобразный "пробный" период), однако необходима онлайн-активация, при которой данные об активации хранятся не только на компьютере пользователя (пример: SLIC-активация), но и на серверах компании.

При этом возможны два подхода подобной активации: ключ многократной установки (MAK, чаще применим для некорпоративного пользователя) и лицензирование через локальный сервис (KMS, чаще применим в компаниях).

Соответственно, при MAK-активации на ключ активации пользователя выделяются 25 виртуальных баллов (Activation Hardware Tolerances) на возможные замены оборудования. При первичной активации счётчик равен 0, в дальнейшем он увеличивается на определенное количество баллов, в зависимости от меняемого оборудования:

```
CD-ROM/CD-RW/DVD-ROM    1
Видеокарта  1
Память, 1 балл на каждый диапазон (0–512 MB, 512 MB–1 GB, 2–4 GB и т.п)
Звуковая карта  2
MAC-адрес 2 (если у вас сетевая с меняемым MAC'ом, и вы его поменяли, это тоже 2 балла)
SCSI-адаптер    2
IDE-адаптер     3
CPU     3
UEFI BIOS ID (фактически, замена материнской платы, хотя возможны экзотические варианты, например её ремонт с заменой микросхемы)   9
Смена серийного номера системного HDD/SDD (фактически, его замена, но возможен и ремонт с заменой электронной части)    11
```

Есть один момент: в случае замены системного диска в первый месяц ранее добавлялся всего лишь 1 балл. На данный момент происходит что-то непонятное, и всегда добавляется 11 баллов.

Соответственно, если вы вдруг решили поменять материнскую плату + процессор + память + видеокарту (пример: замена Intel на AMD с добавлением более новой дискретной видеокарты), вы практически гарантированно получаете 25+ баллов, и, для того, чтобы не покупать Windows 10 (к предыдущим версиям, активированным так же, это тоже применимо) снова, рекомендую предварительно связаться с тех.поддержкой MS и прояснить вопрос, как это правильно сделать в вашем случае.

Несмотря на то, в MS заявляют, что с версии 1607 при любой замене оборудования повторная активация проходит гладко в том случае, если вы используете для входа учётную запись MS, а не локального пользователя, это не всегда работает (проверено именно на замене с AMD AM3+ на AMD AM4 при 32 Гб памяти). Так что будьте аккуратнее!

К сожалению, MS не публикует более подробные данные о баллах активации, конкретике их хранения и начисления и не даёт инструментария узнать, сколько их осталось после той или иной смены оборудования.

**Update 1.** И еще к большему сожалению, даже с версий 1701+ при серьезной замене железа вы можете **безвозвратно**  потерять активацию (и деньги, соответственно, заплаченные за софт!). Будьте осторожнее! Чтобы не посыпать затем голову пеплом, рекомендую перед серьёзной заменой железа вначале звонить в ТП Майкрософта и регистрировать этот случай. По крайней мере, затем вам будет проще требовать у них компенсацию.

**Update 2.** Если Windows 10 вы установили поверх лицензионной Windows 7 бесплатно, в рамках специального предложения, то смена материнской платы или системного диска практически гарантированно грозит утратой лицензии.

**Update 3.** Текущая ситуация. При серьезной замене железа (4+ балла) в 40% случаев вы не сможете подтвердить активацию без использования VPN. При большей замене, скорее всего, вам придётся задуматься об альтернативной активации продукта.

**Update 4.** Впервые поймал балловое изменение из-за обновления AMD fTPM (Firmware-based Trusted Platform Module). Случилось оно в процессе обновления BIOS (было оправдано, поскольку производительность 24-ядерной системы поднялась примерно на 9%, плюс были внедрены защитные патчи), повлекло за собой изменение на 9 баллов и, поскольку я недавно менял второстепенные HDD, вылилось в требование повторной активации.